# Security Rules for Admin Users

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

How can i set up my Security-Rules so that only users with `users/$provider/$user/admin == true` can add and remove new admins.

Here are my Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "users": {
      "$provider": {
        "$user": {
          "profile": {
            ".read": "$user == auth.id && $provider == auth.provider",
            ".write": "$user == auth.id && $provider == auth.provider" 
          },
          "admin": {
            ".read": false,
            ".write": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "blogs": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.provider).child(auth.id).child('admin').val() == true",
      "$blog": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['article', 'time', 'title'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My other question is, can i mix `auth.id` from different `auth.provider`, are they unique? I want drop the `"$provider": {}` in the user hierarchy its a little bit ugly.

Comment: We have an upcoming feature that could assist in providing unique IDs across all providers. If you get a moment, e-mail me at rob@firebase.com - we'd love some feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand correctly what you need:

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "users": {
    "$provider": {
      "$user": {
        "profile": {
          ".read": "$user == auth.id && $provider == auth.provider",
          ".write": "$user == auth.id && $provider == auth.provider" 
        },
        "admin": {
          ".read": "auth.admin == true",
          ".write": "auth.admin == true"
        }
      }
    }
    },
    "blogs": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.provider).child(auth.id).child('admin').val() == true",
    "$blog": {
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['article', 'time', 'title'])"
    }
    }
  }
}
```

On the second question I dont think you need to save the provider at all since if a user loggs in with a different provider it should be taken as a new user unless firebase really keeps track of the only thing that's unique and persistent among logins which is the email and I highly doubt they do. My 99% sure bet is that the `auth.id` changes when the auth providers are switched but that's not hard at all to test is it?

Answer (score 0):

While the `id` attribute is the id for the specified provider, the `uid` is unique across all providers and is intended as the proper index for your users, especially if you're using multiple providers at once.

**Note:** Firebase updated their APIs to no longer return a plain, provider-specific `id` attribute in the security rules `auth` variable for client library versions 1.1.0 or later (released Oct. 3th, 2014).